# Pandas - drop duplicates, keeping the first value in one column, and treating NaNa as a duplicate value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with rows that are essentially duplicates, but either a) have a difference in one column (SecName) that I don't care about, or b) have NaNa in a column.

```
            import pandas as pd

    data = [('BBG000BB0LT4', 'BD3CFT7', 'RAFFLES MEDICAL GROUP', 'SGD', '1', '', '', 'TS78881', ''),
    ('BBG000BB7JQ5', 'BYVLR75', 'OFFICE PPTYS INCOME', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS84562', ''),
    ('BBG000BBR4K2', 'BMT9L19', 'Dassault Aviation S.A.', 'EUR', '', '1', '', '', 'C43914'),
    ('BBG000BBR4K2', 'BMT9L19', 'DASSAULT AVIATION', 'EUR', '1', '', '', 'TS84702', ''),
    ('BBG000BLW102', 'BNG8Z81', 'COHERENT CORP', 'USD', '', '', '1', '', 'C65930'),
    ('BBG000BLW102', 'BNG8Z81', 'COHERENT CORP', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS65520', ''),
    ('BBG000BM0QL7', 'BMYGG87', 'SMITH & WESSON BRANDS', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS69592', ''),
    ('BBG000BN4PQ8', 'BF0X9L7', 'AGRANA BETEILIGUNGS', 'EUR', '1', '', '', 'TS70288', ''),
    ('BBG0019V9M65', 'BF3W461', 'TANDEM DIABETES CARE INC', 'USD', '', '', '1', '', 'C152030'),
    ('BBG0019V9M65', 'BF3W461', 'TANDEM DIABETES CARE', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS100365', '')]

    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PrimID', 'Sedol', 'SecName', 'Curr', 'MSCI', 'FTSE', 'RUSS', 'MSCIID', 'FTAWID'])

    print(data_df)

    desired = [('BBG000BB0LT4', 'BD3CFT7', 'RAFFLES MEDICAL GROUP', 'SGD', '1', '', '', 'TS78881', ''),
    ('BBG000BB7JQ5', 'BYVLR75', 'OFFICE PPTYS INCOME', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS84562', ''),
    ('BBG000BBR4K2', 'BMT9L19', 'Dassault Aviation S.A.', 'EUR', '1', '1', '', 'TS84702', 'C43914'),
    ('BBG000BLW102', 'BNG8Z81', 'COHERENT CORP', 'USD', '1', '', '1', 'TS65520', 'C65930'),
    ('BBG000BM0QL7', 'BMYGG87', 'SMITH & WESSON BRANDS', 'USD', '1', '', '', 'TS69592', ''),
    ('BBG000BN4PQ8', 'BF0X9L7', 'AGRANA BETEILIGUNGS', 'EUR', '1', '', '', 'TS70288', ''),
    ('BBG0019V9M65', 'BF3W461', 'TANDEM DIABETES CARE INC', 'USD', '1', '', '1', 'TS100365', 'C152030')]

    desired_df = pd.DataFrame(desired, columns = ['PrimID', 'Sedol', 'SecName', 'Curr', 'MSCI', 'FTSE', 'RUSS', 'MSCIID', 'FTAWID'])

    print(desired_df)
```

I have tried a few attempts at groupby, drop_duplicates, but none are giving the desired result. I would like to keep the first value from the SecName column and condense all rows where everything matches except for the NaNa values. Hopefully the desired_df explains what I am going for

Edit: here's a solution that works for me:

```
    dx = {'SecName':'first','MSCI':'sum','FTSE':'sum', 'RUSS':'sum','MSCIID':'first','FTAWID':'first'}
    success = data_df.groupby(['PrimID', 'Sedol', 'Curr'], as_index=False, dropna=False).agg(dx)
    
    print(success)
```